# Return row with null values if no rows returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

There are plenty of questions about how to return NULL if a one value returned query returns no rows. But I didn't find anything about a multiple value query returning NULL when no results are returned.

Main query:

```
SELECT UserOpinion.*, x, y, z... FROM subquery, (x) AS x, (y) AS y...
I trust you get the gist.
```

The query I have is a subquery:

```
(SELECT TOP 1                       
        u.BADId,                        
        Date,                       
        State,                      
        Note,                       
        Comment,                        
        Alias,                      
        Title,                      
        UserId,
        o.Id AS OpinionId                   
    FROM                        
        [Opinion] o                 
    RIGHT JOIN                      
        [User] u                        
        ON                          
        o.UserId = u.Id                     
        WHERE                       
        (Date IS NULL OR (Date = (SELECT MAX(Date)                              
                                FROM [Opinion]                              
                                WHERE UserId = o.UserId )))
        AND                             
            u.BADId = 'myvalue') AS UserOpinion;
```

For instance I have tried the following:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT TOP 1                      
        u.BADId,                        
        Date,                       
        State,                      
        Note,                       
        Comment,                        
        Alias,                      
        Title,                      
        UserId,
        o.Id AS OpinionId                   
    FROM                        
        [Opinion] o                 
    RIGHT JOIN                      
        [User] u                        
        ON                          
        o.UserId = u.Id                     
        WHERE                       
        (Date IS NULL OR (Date = (SELECT MAX(Date)                              
                                FROM [Opinion]                              
                                WHERE UserId = o.UserId )))
        AND                             
            u.BADId = 'myvalue' 
        UNION SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) t) AS UserOpinion;
```

This returns NULL, regardless if '*myvalue*' exists. What I want is that it returns the value of the query if an entry exists or that it returns null on every column if it doesn't.

I also tried the following:

```
(COALESCE(SELECT TOP 1                      
    u.BADId,                        
    Date,                       
    State,                      
    Note,                       
    Comment,                        
    Alias,                      
    Title,                      
    UserId,
    o.Id AS OpinionId                   
FROM                        
    [Opinion] o                 
RIGHT JOIN                      
    [User] u                        
    ON                          
    o.UserId = u.Id                     
    WHERE                       
    (Date IS NULL OR (Date = (SELECT MAX(Date)                              
                            FROM [Opinion]                              
                            WHERE UserId = o.UserId )))
    AND                             
        u.BADId = 'myvalue'), NULL) AS UserOpinion;
```

The main issue here is that the entire query returns nothing if '*myvalue*' has no matches. The other queries don't need *myvalue* and making multiple independent queries is not an option for performance constraints.

I am far from an expert in SQL, any suggestions in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Similar questions but not applicable here:

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252797/return-a-single-row-if-no-rows-are-found), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679865/return-a-value-if-no-rows-are-found-sql), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000017/return-a-value-if-no-rows-match) etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with `left outer join`:

```
with s as (<your subquery here>)
select s.*
from (select 1 as x) x left join
     s
     on x.x = 1;
```

This will return either the values in your table.  If thee are no matches, the query returns one row with all columns being `NULL`.

Note:  the CTE is not required.  I only put it in to emphasize the logic for the query.  You can just put your subquery where `s` is.